# i want to inputs be in the center of div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

content is not placed in the Center of Div

i tried to make of form in the center of a div , t think all of values are correct but form doesn't get center
this is the code
the form goes in div of content but form stick to up of div , i don't know why

```css
form#id {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vmin;
  border: solid white 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 29px;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
      <form id="id">
        <label for="input1">write ID</label>
        <input type="number" name="input1" id="input1" placeholder="id">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I horizontally center an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element)

Comment: And many more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: I can't replicate your problem using local IDE and StackSnippet. That being said, this should be closed either as a duplicate, or non-reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo class under `.square:after` is pushing it to the top as it's padding bottom is at 100%. Try commenting the whole block out and you will see the whole form in the middle.

sidenote: You can use `justify-content: center;` as its faster.

Comment: i have wrote - justify-content: center; - for every tag i have  , doesn't work or It is in conflict with a unknown part

Answer (score 0):

I am also beginner, but I think this will help.

try with this once

```
 #id {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
border-radius: 30px;
padding-top: 50%;
}
```

padding-top:50% will bring your form to the center of the square.

Comment: no doesn't work , because want to be responsive and be center of div for every screen , if this %50 was related to div was OK but its related to screen , therefor position for different screen may messed up ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:flex` inside of `.content` class

```
   .content {
      display: flex;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border-radius: 29px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

Also, see: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/center-div-css

```css
.container {
    background: yellow;
    padding:20px;
  }
  
.square {
    position: relative;
    width: 80vmin;
    border: solid white 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin:auto;
  }
  
.content {
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    text-align:center;
  }
  
form#id {
}
  
.square:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;    
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="content">
                <form id="id">
                    <label for="input1">Write-ID</label>
                    <input type="number" name="input1" id="input1" placeholder="id">
                </form>
          </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: its good example of what i want but if you check it on different screen or bigger screen  you can see that aint center in all screens , if i fix it an center it horizontally that would be the exact thing that i want